# rails 3 + jquery + markdown editor = has no method

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, markdown, wysiwym

I'm sort of new to Rails, and very new to jquery. I am trying to get a markdown editor working similar to the one I'm writing in now. The rails app also uses twitter-bootstrap and social-share.

I am currently testing [jquery-wysiwym](http://pushingkarma.com/projects/jquery-wysiwym/) but get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'wysiwym'
```

My page has the following in head:

```
...
<link href="/assets/statuses.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/types.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/wysiwym/wysiwym.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet"type="text/css" />
```

And this at the bottom of the page:

```
...
<script src="/assets/social-share-button.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/wysiwym/wysiwym.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
...
<script src="/assets/application.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.markdown').wysiwym(Wysiwym.Markdown);
    });
</script>

</body>
```

Any help appreciated as I'm a bit stuck.